# Limit display rows in Admin Panel Django

Tags: django, django-admin

I have Admin.py as follows .

```
from django.contrib import admin
from do.models import *

class NewsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=['time','message']

 admin.site.register(do_model,NewsAdmin)
```

I while i go to the admin panel and go to the do_models , it is showing me huge lots of data . I dont want to see all data from the beginning date , is it possible that i can limit data till 20  or 30 lines of data and rest of data should not be shown like paginating  so that it load easily . Kindly suggest .

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
 class NewsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=['time','message']
    list_per_page = 400

 admin.site.register(do_model,NewsAdmin)
```

you can use `list_per_page` to limit the number of rows shown in a single page